# The read_csv() function is reading certain columns with a column type different from the rest

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr, readr, column-types

As found in the `readr` package, I'm using the function `read_csv()` in order to import some data. For some reason, two of the columns (`2013` and `2014`) got identified as `character`, while the rest got identified as `double`. This was not an issue until I tried to tidy the data frames, at which point I ran into this issue:

```
Error in `pivot_longer()` at src/tidy_tertiary.R:5:2:
! Can't combine `2010` <double> and `2013` <character>.
```

The .csv file is formated as follows:

```
country,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020
Austria,3.5723,3.71357,3.7849,3.85794,3.82108,3.85482,3.91019,3.90898,3.91666,3.86284,3.86712
Belgium,3.31314,3.41688,3.49597,3.5459,3.59628,3.66023,3.70912,3.87233,3.82212,3.87927,3.91544
```

and so on. The code that leads to the error is this:

```
library(tidyverse)

tertiary <- tertiary |>
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with("20"),
    names_to = "year",
    values_to = "tertiary")
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Probably you have some typo in the column identified as character, like an empty space or a wrong comma separator or something like this. Try to double-check the original dataset

Comment: I will double-check it right now. I think my mistake was to check the column names for a mistake, instead of the whole column. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your year columns were of type double in the sample dataset. I guess you should examine your CSV file carefully to make sure they are indeed all of types numeric without extra character strings in them. Otherwise, the following solution might give you `NA` or throw an error.

First, you can specify column types in `read_csv`. You can set default column types to double `"d"`, except the `country` column, which should be character `"c"`.

```
library(tidyverse)

read_csv("your_file.csv", col_types = cols(.default = "d", country = "c"))
```

Or change everything except `country` to numeric after you have read in the CSV file (assume it's assigned to `df`).

```r
df %>% mutate(across(-country, as.numeric))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I will check the original dataset again; the `col_types` argument surely will be helpful in the future.